# How to get number of like, share, comment of post of Facebook, Instagram and Twitter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, instagram, instagram-api

I am making ios and android apps and I want to get number of likes, shares, comments of any post that is posted by particular user from his/her Facebook, Instagram and Twitter accounts.

Means how can we get number of like, share, comment of the particular user's post of Facebook, Instagram and Twitter?

Does **Facebook**, **Instagram** and **Twitter** APIs/SDKs support this?

Please provide any reference link to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about twitter or instagram API's but facebook graph API allows you to do this, given that you have the necessary permissions.

You can always check the public data, your own posts and such..if you want to have access to the data of a particular users feed/posts they will need to provide you with that permission. (user_posts in this case)

As for the total count you can retrieve it by adding .summary(1) to the end of your query ex. for likes, comments and shares.

> > me?fields=posts{comments.summary(1),likes.summary(1),shares}

you can also limit the number of comments/likes/shares to zero so that you retrieve only the total count per post. If that is what you want simply ad .limit(0) before the .summary(1) ex. comments.limit(0).summary(1)

Shares however are different from comments/likes/reactions, you can only retrieve the count of shares from graph API therefore you do not need to provide anything other than the "shares" query to the post to recieve that.

Cheers!

Comment: oh & you can test all of this out in the graph API explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/